# How do i create an Add To Calendar link for apple devices?

Tags: php, html, coldfusion-11

i am creating Add To Calendar links for Google, Outlook, Yahoo and Apple. i have created all links except Apple. i want to create a link for apple devices that save the event in apple calendar. my google calendar link that i created is 
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Appointment+Confirmation&dates=20181109T083000Z/20181113T090000Z&details=Vein+Clinics+of+Alexandria+Appointment&location=4904+Seminary+Road+Suite+130+Alexandria,+VA+22311"
i want to create such link for Apple. Can i get some help please.
i am using windows and also testing it on iphone devices.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Only Google Calendar links look like that.
For Apple and everything else you should create an .ics file which is an event file.
You can create it an .ics file here:
https://apps.marudot.com/ical/

Litmus also has a useful article on how to create Add-to-Calendar buttons that I just followed last week and worked for me with some minor tweaking to work on my email template.

https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-create-an-add-to-calendar-link-for-your-emails .

Comment: Thanks Richard, for your help. Actually i have all type of problems with iphone devices to add event in apple calendar.

Answer (score 1):

- I also got this issue. And I resolved it.
- For Apple devices, we must use a .ics file to be the email attachment.
- I'm using this package in node.js
  [calendar-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/calendar-link)
- It can generate the calendar link and the .ics file content.
- Then attach it to your email.
- You can read it as a base64 string like this

```js
 const str = Buffer.from(decodeURIComponent(ics(calendarConfig).toString().split('charse=utf8,')[1])).toString('base64');

// attach this str as an attachment into your email
```

Answer (score 0):

For outlook you can use this pattern https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/deeplink/compose?body=Random%20description&enddt=2023-10-12T09%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&location=here&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2023-10-11T09%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Random%20title

For desktop `deeplink` should be replaced to `action`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35120515)